# Building objective-c code on windows platform

Tags: objective-c, windows

I was doing some iphone development and I could use the iphone-dev toolchain to build to the ARM platform.  Is it possible to build objective-c code to x86?

http://code.google.com/p/iphone-dev/

What should I used to build another toolchain?  Possibly with cygwin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) will compile Objective-C code, regardless of what platform you're on.

However, the Cocoa frameworks only exist on the Mac and iPhone operating systems.  One alternative might be [GNUStep](http://www.gnustep.org/), but that would give you "Cocoa" only about as far as Mac OS X 10.3.

There are some other projects, like [CocoaSharp](http://www.mono-project.com/CocoaSharp) and [MonObjc](http://www.monobjc.net/), that attempt to bridge other languages to Cocoa, and vice versa, but I am not very familiar with them.

So in summary, you can write in Objective-C for any architecture that GCC supports, buy you only get the prebuilt code of the Cocoa frameworks on a Mac.

Answer (score 2):

There is also [Cocotron](http://www.cocotron.org/). There's a good post of how it was used for the Windows port of a desktop client for an iPhone app (FileMagnet) in [Adventures in Cocotron](http://macdaddyworld.com/2008/10/27/adventures-in-cocotron/).